# Inheritance and function calling in PHP

Tags: php, static

I can't figure out how to call an insertValue function for the following setup:

This is my bootstrap. It sets my controller and loads its model. (not really important)

```
<?php
$controller = new Register;
$controller->loadModel('register');
?>
```

This is the controller class which has the loadModel function.

```
class Controller {
public static $model;
public function loadModel($name) {
    $path = 'models/'.$name.'Model.php';
    if(file_exists($path))
    {
        require 'models/'.$name.'Model.php';
        $modelName = $name .'Model';
        $this->model = new $modelName;
    }
}
}
```

This is the parent model class:

```
class Model {
public static $database;

function __construct() {
    $this->database = new Database();
}

}
```

Now the Database class has a function called insertValue() that I want to call, and the register class is where I want to call it from. It's an extension of Controller

The register class appears as follows:

```
class Register extends Controller {


function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->view->render("register", "index", "Register", TRUE);
    }
...
I tried calling it like so:
$this->model->database->insertValue();
but it doesn't even execute.
```

Comment: Maybe this `$this->model->database::insertValue();` with `$database` being a  static it appears?  This a known framework?

Comment: I tried that but it gave me a syntax error. This is my own framework.

Comment: Hm, looks like worked. Maybe problem in insertValue() or other code? Do you have any errors/notices in stdout or log?

Comment: I thought the same before, so I called insertValue in the database class's construct method and it worked perfectly. So it's not the method that's the problem. It's how I'm calling it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your fields *database* and *model* is static. But you are call it dynamicly. Try to remove the static declaration.

Comment: I then deleted the static declaration in my controller class for the model and in my model class for the database and tried $this->model->database->insertValue(); still no go.

Comment: Where are you calls this: `$this->model->database->insertValue();` ? In a constructor of Register? If it is, your code not working because constructor calls earlier than `loadModel` method.

Comment: No, it's not in the constructor, it's in a separate method called register register->register()